# Runnning Soap V2 API on another node

Tags: magento-1.9, php, soap, nginx

Im having an issue where soap calls are failing intermittently - The calls are made from a warehouse management system so when they do fail I loose order status updates and product availability changes.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to run the (Soap V2) api calls on another server.

I use NGINX / PHP-FPM with a separate server running MySQL and Redis.

Comment: What are the specs on your server? What is your transaction average? Are you fulfilling all your orders via the API along with product/category updates?

Comment: Hi Thanks - The front end server has is a 2 core 4gb server with digital ocean (so with an SSD HD too). We take around 100 orders a day - have 4000 active products (around 19,000 products in catalog total)

Comment: Hi Thanks - 

The front end server has is a 2 core 4gb server with digital ocean, and the same for our backend DB server. I have the database replicated to another server where we run backups and have a duplicate front end server that currently isn't in use because trying to use it throws errors.

We take around 100 orders a day - have 4000 active products (around 19,000 products in catalog total)and all orders & products are passed back to our warehouse management system (peoplevox), we also use cloudflare.

Comment: From my experience 2c/4g is under powered for a Magento server. For Rackspace cloud we always recommend a minimum of 8/8. Instead of buying another server you should double your capacity.

Comment: Thanks, I think this sounds like the best option, Im going to look into moving to a different hosting provider and getting a setup closer to what ypu suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your feedback on the post it seems your server does not have enough resources to handle the traffic. Depending on your ERP you can also switch to a batched update for you orders. This will relieve the stress on the server of instant fulfillments.

You can use NewRelic to pinpoint areas that are timing out and it will tell you slow queries as well. If you haven't already optimized your MySQL you should do that and consider Percona as a drop in replacement.

Comment: NewRelic looks like a really good way forward - thanks for your help.